# Best View to achive this layout (To give dimension in ratios or percentage in screen)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

What view would you suggest using, to accomplish this layout in Android:

```
---------------------------------------
|           Cell 1          |         |
-----------------------------  Cell 4 |
|   Cell 2    |  Cell 3     |         |  
---------------------------------------
```

The content of the cells is a Headline and a small text. Cell 2 and 3 should be the same size and together as wide as Cell 1. Cell 1 should be about 3/4 of the screen size and Cell 4 1/4.

Comment: what is ratio b/w cell 1 and cell 4 ? @Thommy

Comment: Well, you could achieve this by using a 1.) GridView with col and row span 2.) RelativeLayout 3.) Nested Linear Layout with layout_weight or the percent library

Comment: i agree with @RobinVinzenz you can easily accomplish this layout using 3).Nested Linear layout

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal">
     <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical>
           Create cell1
           <LinearLayout
                  android:orientation="horizontal">
            Create cell 2
            Create cell 3
           </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
     Create cell 4
</LinearLayout>
```

Use layout weight for proper spacing

Comment: With this way I had the problem, that the text was cutted of.

Comment: Which text was cutted of ? i mean for which cell?

Comment: You can specify weight for eg - For 1st linear layout will have weight of 3 and 1

Comment: The Text in Cells 2 and 3.

Comment: your cell 2 and cell3 combine size should be 3/4 of screen right? and cell2 /cell 3 will be 3/8. If you use above suggested method it will created your required layout. Text is getting cut is separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `GridLayout` :

```
<GridLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="3" >

<YourCell1View
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"/>

<YourCell2View
    android:layout_column="1" />

<YourCell3View  
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="1" />

<YourCell4View
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

</GridLayout>
```

Ofcourse, this is only a basic layout, u have to add the rest of your cell view layout to this. But this should give u your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" <!--choose height according to you need-->
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Nested Weights using Linear Layout]

Nested linear layouts with weights can help you to achieve the same ratio on all screens

**Alternative Solution:-**

Nested weights are generally said to be bad for performance.
You can find **PercentLayout** in support library which can be used for this purpose. there are two direct derivatives for this

- PercentRelativeLayout
- PercentFrameLayout

I have used PercentRelativeLayout here you can get this by adding

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'
```

to you gradle

```
 <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout                        
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vwCell4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:layout_widthPercent="30%" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vwCell1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/vwCell4"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="70%" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vwCell2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/vwCell1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="35%" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vwCell3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/vwCell1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/vwCell4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vwCell2"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="35%" />


    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

[image: PercentRelativeLayout]